# Mutual exclusivity vs. perfect negative correlation

Tags: correlation, terminology

When considering a random experiment with a number of mutually exclusive outcomes.  Is it correct to say that these outcomes have a perfect negative (-1) correlation, or would this be something that is only applicable to the outcomes of different experiments or draws.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of negative correlation says that $P(A \cap B) < P(A)P(B)$, so by considering the fact that either $A$ or $B$ could have probability zero we can see that being mutually exclusive does not imply negative correlation.  But with the exception of this case mutually exclusive events are negatively correlated.

It isn't entirely clear though what you mean by "perfect" negative correlation.  Does that mean that when one event occurs the other does not, and vice versa?  If so the more appropriate concept would be *[complementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_event)*, and to your question mutually exclusive events are not complementary in general.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing here that by "perfect negative correlation" you mean having a Pearson-like correlation of $-1$. For a start, be aware that this kind of correlation makes sense only between pairs of variables that take numerical values, so if you want to apply it to outcomes of an experiment you need to code these outcomes accordingly. One possibility to do so is to define variables corresponding to each possible outcome.

For instance, if $X$ is a fair coin, you can define $X_H=I\{X=H\}$ (equals $1$ if the coin lands $H$ and $0$ otherwise) and $X_T=I\{X=T\}$ (the opposite). Note that this definition implies that the product $X_HX_T$ is always $0$ and the addition $X_H+X_T$ is always $1$.
In this case, moreover, the expected values of $X_H$ and $X_T$ are both $0.5$ and their variances equal $0.5-0.5^2=0.25$. Thus:
\begin{align} \newcommand{\Corr}{{\rm Corr}}
\Corr(X_H,X_T) &= \frac{\mathbb{E}\left((X_H-0.5)(X_T-0.5)\right)}{0.25}  \\[5pt]
               &= \frac{\mathbb{E}(X_HX_T)-0.5\cdot\mathbb{E}(X_H+X_T)+0.25}{0.25}  \\
               &= -1.
\end{align}
So *the variables coding for each outcome of the original variable* do have a correlation of $-1$.

---

EDIT: If the experiment has $N$ mutually exclusive outcomes $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ with corresponding probabilities $p_1,\ldots,p_N$, we can define for $i\neq j$ the variables $Y=I\{X=x_i\}$ and $Z=\{X=x_j\}$. Then the expected values of $Y$ and $Z$ are $p_i$ and $p_j$ respectively, and their variances are $p_i(1-p_i)$ and $p_j(1-p_j)$. Then:

\begin{align}
\Corr(Y,Z) &= \frac{\mathbb{E}\left((Y-p_i)(Z-p_j)\right)}{\sqrt{p_ip_j(1-p_i)(1-p_j)}}  \\[10pt]
           &= \frac{\mathbb{E}(YZ)-p_i\mathbb{E}(Z)-p_j\mathbb{E}(Y)+p_ip_j}{\sqrt{p_ip_j(1-p_i)(1-p_j)}}.
\end{align}

As before, $YZ=0$. Then:
\begin{align}
\Corr(Y,Z) &= \frac{-p_ip_j}{\sqrt{p_ip_j(1-p_i)(1-p_j)}}  \\[10pt]
           &= -\sqrt{\frac{p_ip_j}{(1-p_i)(1-p_j)}}.
\end{align}

So in this case the correlation is negative, but not necessarily $-1$.